# Where can I find the library for org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture

Tags: java, lwjgl

I started making a game in Java, and someone on stackoverflow recommended me LWJGL.
I found some examples, and they worked. Later I wanted to test sprites and every example that I found that loads images imports `org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture`. I can't find that library anywhere. Is there a better alternative, or where can I find this one?

Comment: If you would have used google with the missing import the first results would have hinted you to the according library...

Comment: The problem was that i found the Slick2D with google, but i didn't realize that was what i was looking for...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example you were looking at uses [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) along with LWJGL. You can download the library [here](http://slick.ninjacave.com/slick-util.jar) or the full distribution [here](http://slick.ninjacave.com/slick.zip). Slick2D is used primarily for 2D games, however, even in 3D games it is widely used for loading textures.